# Could any Habsburg kings of Hungary speak Hungarian?

Tags: language, royalty, hungary, austria-hungary

From 1526 to 1918, Hungary was ruled by the Habsburgs.  Could any of the Habsburg kings speak Hungarian, and if so, to what degree?

I know that Sissi, the consort of Franz Joseph I, was particularly popular among the Hungarian people for having learned Hungarian.  This suggests that, at the time, fluency in Hungarian by the royal family was highly unusual.  But was it always unusual, or did any of Franz Joseph's predecessors or successors, like Sissi, make an effort to learn and use the language?

Comment: It's worth noting that in Europe proper, unlike in the U.K. and especially in the U.S. one of the hallmarks of an educated person is the ability to speak  multiple languages. At a minimum basic fluency in at least three of German, French, English and Spanish could be expected of most educated Europeans since the Eighteenth or late Seventeenth Century.

Comment: It is worth to note that up to the 19th most Hungarian nobility didn't speak much Hungarian, neither.

Answer (score 10):

The emperors have often spoken many languages and Hungarian was an important one so one may find numerous Habsburg rulers who spoke Hungarian, too.

For example, [Maximillian II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximilian_II,_Holy_Roman_Emperor) fluently spoke Spanish, French, Latin, Hungarian, and Italian. [Maria Theresa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maria_Theresa) spoke German, Italian, French, Spanish, Latin, Czech and she added Hungarian before she became the empress.

The long-time "last" emperor [Franz Joseph I of Austria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franz_Joseph_I_of_Austria) was led to his skills by his mother Sophia and he was proud about them. He could speak, write, and read in French, Italian, Hungarian, and Czech. His successor Charles I of Austria did speak Czech extremely well (and he wanted some autonomy for the Czech lands around the time of the First World War) but I am not able to find out whether he spoke Hungarian.

However, Charles' recently deceased son Otto von Habsburg (1912-2011) surely did. If we count German, he spoke 15 different languages that included Hungarian and Czech. He has also passed the standard Austrian as well as Hungarian high school (gymnasium) requirements. Nevertheless, even with these credentials, he wasn't allowed to restore the Habsburg monarchy.

Almost all the members of the Habsburg House in the 20th century spoke Hungarian.

Comment: Thanks for the very informative post.  However, the three links to Wikipedia that you provide don't back up any of your claims.  Could you provide some references that do?

Comment: Yes, I know that they don't. I have it from Czech sources: https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxmili%C3%A1n_II._Habsbursk%C3%BD http://www.e-stredovek.cz/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=1315 http://mariaterez.sweb.cz/i007.html  https://is.muni.cz/th/382787/ff_b/Diplomova_pracePDF.txt http://www.cestipanovnici.estranky.cz/clanky/panovnici-cech--5----kralove--cisari--1526---1918.html

Comment: Adding up: Ferdinand the I. of Austria spoke Hungarian, Archduke Joseph, Palatine of Hungary also spoke Hungarian, although he wasn't king. I can provide only Hungarian sources if neccessary.